# Special Character (semicolon) in Password

Tags: .net, oracle, vb.net

I'm trying to change the Oracle DB password using vb.net, it is accepting all the special characters excluding semicolon(;)& double quotes(""). If password contains semicolon, it is throwing unhandled exception as "Input string was not in a correct format."

database-version= Oracle Database 18c Enterprise Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0

```
Public Function oracle_connect(ByVal user As String, ByVal pwd As String, ByVal dbname As String) As Boolean
    oracle_disconnect()
    oraclepwd = pwd
    oracleuser = user
    oraclehost = dbname

    Try
        Dim connStringBuilder As New OracleConnectionStringBuilder()
        connStringBuilder.UserID = oracleuser
        connStringBuilder.Password = "" & oraclepwd & ""
        'connStringBuilder.Password = oraclepwd
        connStringBuilder.DataSource = oraclehost
        connStringBuilder.Pooling = False  


        conn = New OracleConnection(connStringBuilder.ConnectionString)
        mycommand = conn.CreateCommand()            
        
       conn.Open()
            Return True

    Catch ex As Exception
        ' Handle specific exceptions or display error messages
        Return False 
    Finally
        If conn IsNot Nothing AndAlso conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            conn.Close()
        End If
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: Given that the semicolon is used as a delimiter between the fields in the connection string, of course you can't just stick one in the middle of the password without escaping it. You shouldn't be building the connection string using concatenation like that anyway. Use a connection string builder, which is included in every ADO.NET provider. That will handle the escaping for you.

Comment: Dear jmcilhinney,
Thank you for your suggestion. I am relatively new to the industry and I truly appreciate your advice. I did try using the OracleConnectionStringBuilder as you suggested, but I am still facing the same issue with the connection string.

Answer (score 1):

From the SQL manual [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/CREATE-USER.html#GUID-F0246961-558F-480B-AC0F-14B50134621C):

Passwords can contain any single-byte, multibyte, or special characters, or any combination of these, from your database character set, **with the exception of the double quotation mark (") and the return character**. If a password starts with a non-alphabetic character, or contains a character other than an alphanumeric character, the underscore (_), dollar sign ($), or pound sign (#), then it must be enclosed in double quotation marks. Otherwise, enclosing a password in double quotation marks is optional.

And I just tested it:

```
SQL> create user tsc identified by "My;test123";

User created.

SQL> grant connect to tsc;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> connect tsc/"My;test123"@//localhost/test23
Connected.
```